# TinyMapper: bind using expression

Tags: c#, .net, mapper, tinymapper

Current code throw exception `Expression is not a MemberExpression`:

```
TinyMapper.Bind<StudenRecord, StudentEntity>(cfg =>
{                
    cfg.Bind(x => $"{AppSettings.AvatarBaseUrl}/{x.AvatarUrl}", t => t.AvatarUrl);
});
```

Is there a way i could achieve my goal using TinyMapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, TinyMapper doesn't support a `MethodCallExpression` it supports only `MemberExpression`, as a workaround, you can create [custom type converter](https://github.com/TinyMapper/TinyMapper/wiki/Custom-mapping)